# Different exception specifier with g++ 6.2

Tags: c++, exception, g++, throw

Could someone explain to me why this code doesn't compile with g++ version 6.2.0, but compiles fine with clang++ version 3.9.0-svn274438-1 and icpc version 16.0.2

```
$ cat wtf.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>
void *operator new(std::size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc);
void *operator new(std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc) { void *p; return p; }

$ g++-6 wtf.cpp -c 
wtf.cpp: In function ‘void* operator new(std::size_t)’:
wtf.cpp:4:7: error: declaration of ‘void* operator new(std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc)’ has a different exception specifier
 void *operator new(std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc) { void * p; return p; }
       ^~~~~~~~
wtf.cpp:3:7: note: from previous declaration ‘void* operator new(std::size_t)’
 void *operator new(std::size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using C++11 or later?

The original operator new() declarations in C++98

```
throwing:   
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);

nothrow:
void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw();

placement:
void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();
```

Have been changed in C++11 to use **noexcept** keyword:

```
throwing:   
void* operator new (std::size_t size);

nothrow:    
void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) noexcept;

placement:  
void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
```

[Reference link.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/)

Comment: By adding `-std=c++03`, g++ compiles fine. But that doesn't explain why I get this error message, right? Line 3 of `wtf.cpp` still has the same exception specifier as line 4, I think.

Comment: @BigDawg - `throw()` and `noexcept` have similar effect, but the `throw (std::bad_alloc)` is totally different from not specifying the exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In **GCC 6** the default mode for C++ has [changed](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) to **C++14**. Until **GCC 5** it was **C++98**.

The `operator new` declaration has changed slightly in C++11. It has to do with the fact that the throwing exception specification is [deprecated in C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3051.html), and the introduction of the `nothrow` declaration:

- `throw (std::bad_alloc)` has been omitted
- `throw()` is replaced with `nothrow`

For best backwards-compatibility you should specify which C++ standard you're targeting using the `-std` argument, like this:

```
$ g++-6 -std=c++98 wtf.cpp -c
```